# Reading an extension file through Jquery

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to read Google chrome extension static html file in my content script and load it into div as follows:

```
 $(menuDiv).load(chrome.extension.getURL("popup.html"));
```

However, I am getting the error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   chrome-extension://kefhgglpbeopmaaljlplohlfgkdekgmc/popup.html.
>   Cross origin requests are only
>   supported for HTTP.

Any idea how to solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Content scripts are not allowed to make cross-site XMLHttpRequests:
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html

As a workaround, have your content script send a request to your background page, let the background page fetch popup.html's contents, and then pass a message back to your content script with the contents.

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html